# Find out all the files bash / dash / sh reads during startup

Tags: bash, shell, monitoring, strace

## Context

- Certain modifications to my start up scripts ended up with `dash: 1: [[: not found` and similar with `ash` shells.
- I naturally assumed it was some profile (.profile, etc) based script that used `bash`'s `[[` while it's being run with POSIX based shells. But couldn't figure out which one.
- So decided to run it under `strace` to find out all the files being read. The result surprised me - none of the profile based files were listed in the strace output.

## Outcomes

```sh
$ strace -fe trace=%file bash -c exit

execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "exit"], 0x7ffc430c3870 /* 67 vars */) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
stat("/home/user", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/user", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/user/.cargo/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/.local/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/.local/opt/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/.cargo/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/.npm/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/.cargo/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/.local/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/.local/opt/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/.cargo/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/.npm/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/user/workspace/go/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/sbin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1166912, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1166912, ...}) = 0
access("/usr/bin/bash", X_OK)           = 0
stat("/usr/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1166912, ...}) = 0
access("/usr/bin/bash", R_OK)           = 0
stat("/usr/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1166912, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1166912, ...}) = 0
access("/usr/bin/bash", X_OK)           = 0
stat("/usr/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1166912, ...}) = 0
access("/usr/bin/bash", R_OK)           = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Running with plain `strace -f bash |& grep profile` and such also seem to show nothing.

## Questions

1. How do I list all the files that the shell ends up actually reading? (Note that the question is not what it's supposed to read according to the docs, but rather what is actually *being* read in runtime)
2. Why does the above not show any of the `.profile`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc` `.bashrc` etc?
3. (A bit off topic) Why does a series of `ENOENT`s happen here - `stat("/home/user/.cargo/bin/bash", 0x7ffe62a61e90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` - It appears it's searching for bash on all the env paths. But why does this happen? (How to find what is actually executing the `bash` command here which results in the PATH search)

Comment: I suspect bash is smart enough not to load the entire runtime configuration if it is called to execute `exit`. The strace show your PATH is searched until `bash` is found and then it checks the file permission for the executable and then preforms the exit. You may try with `bash -c "echo $HOME"` and see if that doesn't prompt bash to load further runtime config files. Your question appears to be an **XY Problem**. See: [**What is the XY problem?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What are you doing this for? Curiosity? Or, something else?

Comment: The `ENOENT`s are the result of the shell looking for bash in all the placed in your PATH that it isn't. You don't have a `"/home/quarkstone/.cargo/bin/bash"` do you?

Comment: Maybe install https://gist.github.com/tripleee/0aea6984632c30956329 and symlink it to `[[` and see if you get anything useful back.

Comment: BTW, `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -lix` is a good place to start... when your shell is bash, which of course isn't the case here. Larger point is that if one sets a `PS4` that includes the filename in trace output, then you don't need strace.

Comment: (I'd also strongly suggest looking at sysdig as an alternative to strace; far more powerful filtering, traces the whole system rather than individual processes, and does that with orders-of-magnitude less overhead, to the point that it's very much usable in practice on live production systems; with the new eBPF backend, there's not even any kernel module needed).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, PS4 is a neat trick, thanks! Also, personally, I tend to use `perf` most of the time myself. Just used `strace` for the simplicity sake here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing all the files that the shell is reading.

`/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` are login files that bash only reads if it's invoked as a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell). `/etc/bashrc` (or `/etc/bash.bashrc`) and `~/.bashrc` are customization files for interactive sessions (with quirks that aren't relevant here). None of these files are read when interpreting a script or running a single command with `-c`.

Bash does read the file whose name is in the `BASH_ENV` environment variable when it starts. But normally this environment variable is unset so bash doesn't read any file.

Bash apparently likes to obtain information about its own binary when it starts. I don't know what that's for, but it's built-in behavior, not behavior that comes from some startup script.

None of this will help you in any way to understand why a script that contains bash constructs is being run with dash. The reason the script is run with dash is probably that `/bin/sh` is dash on your system: systems rarely invoke `dash` explicitly. If you don't know which script is causing this or if you don't understand how that script is called, your investigation should to start from the circumstances under which the message appears. If it's a login-time script, you need to understand how login works on your system and what programs are invoked. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) may help with that.

Comment: Ah, excellent! Thank you addressing all of my questions beautifully, makes a lot of sense now. I'm assuming `bash -xv` is as good as you can get short of going through the profle + bashrc (login + interactive) files one by one to find out which script is using the `[[`.

Comment: Why do you not strace `dash` instead?

Comment: @tripleee - Yes, after the excellent solution from Gilles, I did end up figuring it out. Ran it with `dash -lix` and figured it out.

Comment: I figured what I was missing were the `login` and `interactive` clues from this solution, and then `stracing` it gave me what I wanted.